# Why am I getting this error in AWS Device farm? Tests skipped due to test package parsing error. Please check Parsing result for more details

Tags: amazon-web-services, calabash, calabash-android, aws-device-farm

In AWS Device Farm, I created a new run.  I chose native application.  I uploaded my APK.  I chose Calabash as the tests.  I got this error message:

```
Tests skipped due to test package parsing error. Please check Parsing result for more details.
```

I downloaded the Parsing result.  Here's what it said:

> Failed to run cucumber dry-run command. See the information below for more details.

Here are the contents for the Parsing result:

```
'cucumber --dry-run --format json --out /tmp/scratchvxnAeX.scratch/tmpF6f5Xx' failed.    
Could not find proper version of cucumber (2.99.0) in any of the sources    
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

I have some `.rb` page objects.  I added `require 'calabash-android'` to the top of those files.  Then I made a new run and ran it.  It worked.

**How I got to the solution**

Through Google I came across CALABASH_TEST_PACKAGE_DRY_RUN_FAILED [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/troubleshooting-calabash.html).

Running this command failed: `cucumber-ios --dry-run --format json features`

I figured that was for ios.  So I tried this: `bundle exec calabash-android run .\app-releaseStaging.apk --dry-run`.  I got this error:

```
uninitialized constant Calabash::ABase (NameError)
```

I wasn't getting that error when running locally.

According to [this](http://sthen.blogspot.com/2015/02/calabash-android-command-line-options.html):

> `-d`, `--dry-run` Invokes formatters without executing the steps.  This also omits the loading of your support/env.rb file if it exists.

I had `require 'calabash-android'` inside `env.rb`.  So I moved it to my page objects.  Then it worked.

You may find the [aws-device-farm-calabash-tests-for-sample-app](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-device-farm-calabash-tests-for-sample-app) useful.